# Why does triggering a 'click' result in a different Event on radioButton and Checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, jquery-trigger

Triggering a click Event on a Radio Button and a Checkbox results in a slightly different result when you look at the event thta is triggered:

So triggering click on a RadioButton by doing

```
$('#radio01').trigger('click');
```

and catching the event on the radio button by

```
$('#radio01').on('click', reactToClick);

function reactToClick(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

Shows me a different result then doing the same on a checkbox:

```
$('#myCheckbox').trigger('click');
```

&

```
$('#myCheckbox').on('click', reactToClick);

function reactToClick(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

The Checkbox & RadioButton look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" name="checkme" />
<label for="myCheckbox">Check Me</label>

<input type="radio" id="radio01" name="radio" value="0" />
<label for="radio01">Option 1</label>
```

You can see the different output in [this Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/xczSyaB8tgBH2Ai7YXuw?p=preview) i created to visualize the problem.
Can anyone tell me why it behaves differently?

EDIT:
As some answers came already, this is what happens in my browser when i click on those Trigger-Buttons in the Plunkr:
[image]

Comment: literally, the only difference in your plunkr is the timestamp on the events.

Comment: The console might show a different excerpt, but the objects are probably for all intents and purposes the same

Comment: For the checkbox the only difference is the `"isTrusted": false`, with `.trigger()` instead of `true`, and it's quite logical because the event is triggered with a script which can be a security problem.

Comment: And triggering a radioButton with a script is not a security problem?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ury6hs8a/